# Not able to find a element using xpath or css

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I have an element placed in this path:

```
html>body>main>#wrapper>div#content 
 ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom 
 ui-accordion-content-active>
   div#AddEcpDiv/form#form3/div/table/tbody/tr/td/input#SaveCard
```

The type is checkbox and I need to click on this.

When I run the script Ruby is throwing `Element not found` error. Can someone tell me the syntax on how to click this checbox. Tried both Xpath and CSS, but not successful.

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The SaveCard field is required."
 id="SaveCard" name="SaveCard" type="checkbox" value="true" onchange="">
```

Note: using Selenium web driver on Ruby.

Comment: Try `driver.find_element(:css, '#SaveCard')`...

Comment: If you are using id,following also should work : `driver.find_element(:id, "SaveCard")`

Comment: Tried css  Arup provided earlier also.  @driver.find_element(:css, '#SaveCard').clickThis is the errror C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/
ib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:51:in `assert_ok': Cannot click on ele
ent (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)

Comment: And i have noticed that web page I'm accessing it have 2 elements with same name and I think selenium is picking up first one which is not visible. HTML TAGS  <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The SaveCard field is required." id="SaveCard" name="SaveCard" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The SaveCard field is required." id="SaveCard" name="SaveCard" style="margin-top: 10px" type="checkbox" value="true" />

Comment: Finally this is resolved. I found a way by looping the elements with name SaveCard and clicking a visible element.